# Как получить Item под курсором мыши?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Обрабатывать `MouseMove` или `PreviewMouseMove`. Тип контейнера - любой `ItemsControl`. В качестве ItemsSource указано нечто `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. Так вот при наведении мыши на элемент управления мне надо получить экземпляр этого самого `MyClass`, который хранится в контейнере.

Для приближения к реальности, пусть будет некий объект типа `object` в VM, который будет содержать экземпляр коллекции, контейнер которого находится под курсором мыши. Контейнер может быть **ЛЮБОГО ТИПА**. Даже самый обычный `ItemsControl`

Comment: если используете Caliburn то можно привязать событие MouseOver к методу в ViewModel передав внутрь $dataContext

Answer (score 1):

Есть много методов. Например, такой:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="<тут привязываетесь к нужной коллекции>"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <!-- тут отображение вашей VM, замените на то, что нужно -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

и code-behind:

```
void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var item = b.DataContext;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mouse entered: {item}");
}

void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var item = b.DataContext;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mouse left: {item}");
}
```

---

Правильный метод зависит от того, для чего именно вам нужен этот самый элемент.

---

Есть, конечно, путь через `MouseMove` у самого контейнера, но он длинный и неизящный.

В XAML:

Есть много методов. Например, такой:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="<тут привязываетесь к нужной коллекции>"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <!-- тут отображение вашей VM, замените на то, что нужно -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

и code-behind:

```
void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var item = b.DataContext;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mouse entered: {item}");
}

void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var item = b.DataContext;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mouse left: {item}");
}
```

---

Правильный метод зависит от того, для чего именно вам нужен этот самый элемент.

---

Если очень хочется навесить обработчик именно на список, можно сделать так:

В XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="<тут привязываетесь к нужной коллекции>"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         MouseMove="OnMouseMove">
```

и в code-behind:

```
void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (ListBox)sender;
    var coordinatesAboutList = e.GetPosition(b);
    var itemInsideContainer = b.InputHitTest(coordinatesAboutList);
    var container = FindContainer(itemInsideContainer, b);
    if (container == null)
        return;
    var item = b.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(container);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mouse moved over: {item}");
}

ListBoxItem FindContainer(IInputElement itemInsideContainer, ListBox b)
{
    ListBoxItem candidate = null;
    for (DependencyObject currentItem = (DependencyObject)itemInsideContainer;
         currentItem != null;
         currentItem = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentItem))
    {
        candidate = currentItem as ListBoxItem;
        if (candidate != null)
            break;
    }
    if (candidate != null)
    {
        for (DependencyObject parent = (DependencyObject)itemInsideContainer;
             parent != b;
             parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent))
        {
            if (parent == null)
                return null;
        }
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

Но лучше развесить отлов мыши на `ItemTemplate` или `ItemContainerStyle`, не придётся бегать по визуальному дереву в поисках нужного элемента.

Comment: У меня нет такой роскоши, как возможность в каждый темплейт айтема ставить обработчики. Обработчики надо ставить либо на форму, либо на сам ItemControl.

Comment: Пытаюсь запилить бехавиор на драг дроп между контейнерами с одинаковым типом содержимого. Ну ладно, старт драг я могу и с элемента внутри контейнера сделать, но отпускать то надо в контейнер. А для этого нужно знать в какую позицию в коллекцию внутри ВМ бросить айтем, который у меня в дате драга, а для этого нужно знать какой элемент у меня лежит внутри контейнера под курсором мыши (ЕСЛИ ТАКОЙ ЕСТЬ, ведь контейнер моежт быть и пуст, или элементов не хватает на заполнение всей области

Comment: @iRumba: Почему нет такой роскоши? Ну и обработчики может вполне навесить Behaviour, это как раз небольшая проблема.

Comment: Я же написал почему... там столько букавок, неужели зря старался? ) Все дело в контейнере, куда будем спускать драганую дату )

Comment: @iRumba: Всё равно непонятно. Вам же нужно знать только, на каком из _существующих_ айтемов был выполнен дроп? Там более, если вам не нужно всё время отслеживать, просто сделайте то, что у меня в коде `OnMouseMove`, только не на MouseMove, а на дропе.

Comment: А как тогда дропать просто в контейнер? В любом случае это неудобно... Придется подключать бехавиор на контейнер и на айтемы. А я хочу на что то одно.

Comment: @iRumba: Вроде можно только на контейнер. Контейнер может выяснить, что за item в нём лежит, по идее (`ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(container)`).